# How to bind property in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

In My solution i have passed one autogenerated grid.In this grid one column added by using datatemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IdTextBlockTemplate">
 <TextBlock>
   <Run Text="l" Loaded="OnLoad" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Wingdings" />
   <Run Text="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
 </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

In xaml.cs

```
 private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
 {
    switch (e.Column.Header.ToString())
    {   
        case "ConnectionState":
            GridViewDataColumn item = new GridViewDataColumn();
            item.CellTemplate = Resources["IdTextBlockTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            item.IsReadOnly = true;
            item.Header = "ConnectionState";
            e.Column = item;                    
            break;  
    }
}
```

But this will work when header is equal to "connectionstate"

in onload method i have added

private void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

```
        if (((sender as Run).DataContext as DataRowView)[8].ToString() == "OffLine")
        {
            (sender as Run).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            (sender as Run).Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0));
        }

    }
```

Now am localizing my solution .I am changing english language to chinese.
That time header connection state will convert to chinese.
But am not able to see the value inside the Connectionstate column

when change the language,the property also need to change.How to do that?

How to solve this?

Comment: Look into implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` with data binding in WPF, for updating properties/views. Your favourite search engine will point you in the right direction...

Comment: DynamicResources are ideal for such scenarios. Create one ResourceDictionary for every language in which you store the string values. Then bind to those in your XAML/Code behind using a DynamicResource binding. Now you can swap the ResourceDictionary at runtime and change the language of the whole GUI.